# How change tables name in a loop in sql (snowflake)?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am beginner in SQL. I wrote a code to produce a `table(P_ELIG)` for one year. Then I put a while loop to reproduce the table for more than 1 year. But, I received the following error when the code reached the `while`

> Syntax error: unexpected 'while'.

```
set cdm_schema = 'DEIDENTIFIED_PCORNET';
set demographic = $cdm_schema || '.DEID_DEMOGRAPHIC';
set prescribing = $cdm_schema || '.DEID_PRESCRIBING';

-- Loop over the desired years

set start_year = 2015;
set end_year = 2020;

while $start_year <= $end_year do

 -- Convert the start and end year to strings
 set start_date = $start_year || '-01-01';
 set end_date = $start_year || '-12-31';
 set cut_year1 = $start_year + 1; 
 set cut_year = $tcut_year1 || '-01-01';

  create or replace table P_ELIG_$start_year as
  select d.PATID,
      d.BIRTH_DATE,
      round(datediff(day,d.birth_date,$start_date)/365.25) as AGE,
      max(dth.DEATH_DATE::date) as death_date,
      datediff(day, $cut_year,max(dth.DEATH_DATE)) as days_to_death,
      max(coalesce(enc.discharge_date, enc.admit_date)) as censor_date,
      datediff(day, $cut_year, censor_date) as days_to_censor,
      min(p.rx_order_date) as index_date
  from identifier($demographic) d
  join identifier($prescribing) p on d.patid = p.patid
  group by d.PATID, d.BIRTH_DATE;

  set start_year = $start_year + 1;

end while;
```

How Can I solve this issue? is it necessary to put it in specific block?

Comment: Hi - I would start by reading the documentation on SQL scripting. Also, just as an FYI, having a table per year would normally be a really bad design. Just create one table with a year column

Comment: no if-then-else and no while loops in sql

Comment: @marcothesane Snowflake scripting does support control statements

Comment: Your `WHILE` statement needs to have the condition in brackets like `WHILE (<condition>)` as per the [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/snowflake-scripting/while).